# How to delay an animation in Kotlin?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

Can someone help me with delaying an animation before every repetition with a duration x?

Here is my animation:

```
val animations = arrayOf(-140f).map { translation ->
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationX", translation).apply {
        startDelay = 1000L     //Update
        duration = 800
        repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
    }
}

val set = AnimatorSet()
    set.playTogether(animations)
    set.start()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `objectanimator.setStartDelay(your_delay_in_millis);` method

Comment: How can I implement this line in my code? @kostyaBoss

Comment: in apply block use needed param. Naming should be like startDelay or something similar to it

Comment: I updated my question, the code only delays the animation at the start but I want it to get delayed after every round.

Comment: Do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy! just a little change to your code:

1- Change `repeatCount` from `INFINITE` to 1

2- Add `doOnEnd` and `start`

3- Add your delay time!

Finally, your code must be like this:

```
 val animations = arrayOf(-140f).map { translation ->
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.viewYatch, "translationX", translation).apply {
                     //Update
                duration = 800
                repeatCount = 1
                repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
                doOnEnd {
                    startDelay = 1000L
                    start()
                }
            }
        }

        val set = AnimatorSet()
        set.playTogether(animations)
        set.start()
```